# What does cp ${LOCALFILE} ${LOCALFILE}.${DOW} do?

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, aix

Can someone please tell me what does the following command do:
cp ${LOCALFILE} ${LOCALFILE}.${DOW}
I am trying to fix an issue in .ksh which creates duplicate files with '.' at the end of extension, say for example .pdf is .pdf. with '.' in the end..
this occurs after FTP command and after FTP is successful above command is there..
I am working with AIX 4.3

Comment: All of the '${}' constructs are references to variables. The variable 'DOW' may not be set, in which case you're copying `${LOCALFILE} to ${LOCALFILE}.` You're going to have to give us the whole script if you want a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the name, I guess `DOW` means “day of week”.

Since your files get copied to `*.pdf.`, the variable `DOW` is not defined (or empty).

Somewhere above the `cp` line, there should be some code like the following:

```
DOW=`date +%u`
```